# c# Designer View for collapsed Expander / Stackpanel

Tags: c#, designer, expander

I cannot see what is inside a collapsed Expander or Stack Panel.

How can I see its content in the visual Designer?

The Expander is in a StackPanel and the StackPanel is in a ScrollViewer

```
<Expander Header="{StaticResource CategoryTreeMetadataHeader}" IsExpanded="False" 
                      Style="{StaticResource newExpanderStyle}" Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
 <Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition />
   <RowDefinition />
   <RowDefinition />
   <RowDefinition />
   <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="150px" />
   <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{StaticResource Treename}"/>
  <TextBox   Style="{StaticResource TextBox3D}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="TreenameTextBox"></TextBox>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{StaticResource Comment}"/>
  <TextBox   Style="{StaticResource TextBox3D}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="CommentTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" MinLines="5"></TextBox>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="{StaticResource TypeaheadChars}"/>
  <ext:IntegerUpDown Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="100" Name="TypeaheadCharsTextBox"  Value="3" Increment="1" Maximum="7" Minimum="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="ArchivingLabel" Text="{StaticResource ArchivingEnabled}"/>
  <CheckBox  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="ArchivingCheckBox" IsChecked="True" Checked="ArchivingCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="ArchivingCheckBox_Unchecked" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="RetentionLabel" Text="{StaticResource RetentionEnabled}"/>
  <CheckBox  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="RetentionCheckBox" IsChecked="True" Checked="RetentionCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="RetentionCheckBox_Unchecked" />
 </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

---

**for expander:**

1) you have a expander:
[image]

2) right-click your expander and make sure that **Expand Expander** is checked[image]

3) make the expander bigger, the grey area is the content[image]

---

**for a collapsed stackPanel**, i would just edit the xaml code

```
<StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

to

```
<StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Visibility="Visible"/>
```

and when you are done, just set Visibility back to collapsed

Comment: many thanks for the answer!
unfortunately in VS 2010 there is no menu item called "expand expander"

Comment: @GeraldTrost oh, it's VS 2010. ok i will try to find a solution for 2010 then ;)

Comment: @GeraldTrost can you please post the xaml code from your expander?